# is it possible to make the chatgpt only contains result content without intro or summary

Tags: chatgpt

I need to generate some job description, now I trying to use chatGPT to generate it, this is the prompt looks like:

```
please generate a job descriptions of java develop engineering. the output only contains description, no other info. each item seperate by *. this is an example: * maintaining Java-based applications, contributing to the design, coding, testing, and deployment of software solutions * excellent problem-solving skills, attention to detail, and the ability to work independently or as part of a team
```

this prompt generate the result, is it possible to remove the intro and summary from the result? I just want the JD items.

Comment: ChatGPT is known for being annoyingly and stupidly verbose. I say also stupidly because even if you ask it not to be verbose it will still be in many cases. Are you using the API or the UI?

Comment: I am using the API, seems told him not to output the intro and summary does not work as expect. I want to embedded the generation content within my workflow.

Answer (score 2):

Usually when I need a short answer that can be handled by a software, I'll ask chatgpt to return in the format that I want (by example, `markdown` or `json`), and at end of my command I add this sentence:

`Act as a computer software: give me only the requested output, no conversation.`

Another idea is something similar to the [Act as a linux terminal prompt](https://www.engraved.blog/building-a-virtual-machine-inside/):

`I want you to act as a linux terminal. I will type commands and you will reply with what the terminal should show. I want you to only reply with the terminal output inside one unique code block, and nothing else. do not write explanations. do not type commands unless I instruct you to do so.`

You can even include a penalty instruction like:

`You'll loose points if the returned output contains any content other than requested output`.

The last resource is to try a regular expression to replace the chatgpt non wanted talk. Usually it'll contain something like:

> Here is the requested content in markdown format.

So, to prevent this to get returned to the user, I run a regular expression to replace it (**JavaScript**):

```
const clearAnswer = answer.replace(/.+in markdown format:\n\n/gm, '');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this promt. For me it always works:

> Please generate a job description for a Java Development Engineer.
> Only include the description items, and separate each item with an
> asterisk (*).
>
> Job Description:
> *

Comment: If the GPT still adds something at the end, you can easily cut it off with an expression like:
if stroke[0] != "*":